# Split videos into segments using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 10000 videos and I want to split each video into five segments

I know previously how to segment video using ffmpeg but I do not know how to use it with a large number of videos

the names of videos are:
1.avi,
2.avi,
3.avi,
.......
.....,
10000.avi

*I want to use for loop with ffmpeg*
         can you please help me?!!!!

Comment: Take a look at Python OpenCV module

Comment: Thanks A LOT for your response

Comment: See the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133119/ffmpeg-splitting-large-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,10000) DO (
 ffmpeg -i "C:\video-splitter-master\%%G.avi" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:00:00 -t 0:00:02 "C:\video-splitter-master\%%Greem1.avi"
 ffmpeg -i "C:\video-splitter-master\%%G.avi" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:00:00 -t 0:00:03 "C:\video-splitter-master\%%Greem2.avi"
 ffmpeg -i "C:\video-splitter-master\%%G.avi" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:00:00 -t 0:00:04 "C:\video-splitter-master\%%Greem3.avi"
 ffmpeg -i "C:\video-splitter-master\%%G.avi" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:00:00 -t 0:00:05 "C:\video-splitter-master\%%Greem4.avi"
 ffmpeg -i "C:\video-splitter-master\%%G.avi" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 0:00:00 -t 0:00:06 "C:\video-splitter-master\%%Greem5.avi"

 )
 pause
```