# split the video into five chunks using ffmpeg and batch script

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to split videos into five chunks using ffmpeg

the first chunk represents 20% of the whole video
the second chunk represents 40% of the whole video
the third chunk represents 60% of the whole video
the fourth chunk represents 80% of the whole video

the fifth chunk represents 100% of the whole video

I write the algorithm but I do not know how to write the batch code:
1. find the duration of the video 
2. store the duration in variable 
3. divided the duration by 5
4. split the video

**I want a batch script that takes the duration of the video then store the value of duration in the variable**

this is how I can take the duration of the video

```
ffmpeg -i C:\video-splitter-master\1.avi 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | sed 's@\..*@@g' | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }'
```

**but how I can store the duration value in the variable?**

can you please help me?

Comment: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.0 -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 00:00:10.0 output.mp4` will copy the first ten seconds from the start point of 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split videos into five segment using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276112/split-videos-into-five-segment-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: The stderr output from ffmpeg is not meant to be machine parsed. [Use ffprobe instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration). Then you can eliminate `grep`, `cut`, `sed`, `sed`, and `awk`.